# how to define cost function as root mean squared logrithmic error in tensorflow in python

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, loss-function

I want to use a self-designed cost function. can anyone please help me with the code for defining a cost function for my regression model as root mean square logarithmic error

Answer (score 1):

You can pass an arbitrary loss function into your `model.compile()` call. SO you could implement your own RMLSE function something like this:

```py
def rmsle(y_true, y_pred):
  eps = tf.constant(0.00001)
  return tf.math.sqrt(
      tf.reduce_mean(
        tf.pow(tf.math.log(eps + y_true) - tf.math.log(eps + y_pred), 2)))
```

and use it in a model.

Here is a complete example you can replicate (here we are trying to treat the mnist digits as a regression problem which is obvs a little silly but you can adapt to your own problem as you see fit):

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.enable_eager_execution()

mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0
y_train, y_test = tf.cast(y_train, tf.float32), tf.cast(y_test, tf.float32)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(1,activation='sigmoid')
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=rmsle)
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5)
```